# Which one is best to give a shadowColor, Radius, Opacity and cornerRadius for a UIButton? button extension or IBDesignable?

Tags: swift4, swift-extensions

i'm new to swift,i know little bit about Extension and IBdesignable.
extensions will give effects at runtime and IBDesignable will give live rendering in storyboard without run the application.which is more effective?
i want to know deep in this subject..please help!!

thanks!!

Comment: [https://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/](https://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) you can refer this one.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani, Thanks for your comment . But, when i used IBDesignable and IBInspectable, it takes time while at compiling. why?